# Magento Widget displays outside CMS page area, stops CMS page text being displayed (?)

Tags: php, magento, widget, magento-1.6

Following on from my previous post, I created a simple 'hello world' style widget which parses a google-docs hosted excel csv and prints a table from the data - this part works wonderfully, but when I insert it into a CMS page, it displays right at the top directly beneath the 'breadcrumbs' block, you can see an example [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g20tq.png), where the two sets of test text are meant to come before and after the table.

Please let me know which code would be useful to post, I don't want to post it all and create a wall of text!

Here is my block php file which just calls (I think) a template file which does all the parsing.

```
<?php
class Urbanrider_Scooterlistwidget_Block_Table
extends Mage_Core_Block_Abstract
implements Mage_Widget_Block_Interface
{
    protected function _Construct() {       

    $this->setTemplate('urbanrider/scooterlistwidget/table.phtml');

}
```

}
?>

Is this the right way to go about this?  It's effectively a 'Hello World' widget.

Edit:

I have also tried using 'protected function toHtml()' and put all of the phtml template in there but I'm getting the same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do something like this in the cms:

```
(test before)
{{block type="urbanrider/scooterlistwidget" block_id="myblock" template="urbanrider/scooterlistwidget/table.phtml"}}
(test after)
```

Comment: Hey, sorry I should have mentioned, the test messages are on the CMS page, between them is where the widget is inserted

Comment: I edited the answer above to reflect how I was able to make it work in a CMS page.  see if this will work for you.  cheers.

Comment: Edward, did this fix it for you?  As I mentioned, I was able to make it work this way. thx sconnie

Comment: Hello, sorry for the late reply, yes it works, and this way is so much simpler than what I was trying to do, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can also set the template from block class like this:

```
<?php
class Urbanrider_Scooterlistwidget_Block_Table
extends Mage_Core_Block_Abstract
implements Mage_Widget_Block_Template
{
    protected function _toHtml() {       

    $this->setTemplate('urbanrider/scooterlistwidget/table.phtml');
    return parent::_toHtml();

}
```